# jQuery: How to slice(-5) elements from the same class in all <h3> tags in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery UI with the Accordion feature.

I have this structure:

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-11" aria-controls="ui-id-12" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="job-title job-title2">title</span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <br>
    <span class="subtext">subtext</span>
    <br>
</h3>
<div> 
    Content
</div>
```

and I want to remove all `ui-icon` classes and leave only one (meaning `.slice(-5).remove()` so it will look like this:

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-11" aria-controls="ui-id-12" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="job-title job-title2">title</span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <br>
    <span class="subtext">subtext</span>
    <br>
</h3>
<div> 
    Content
</div>
```

I got all confused with trying to apply this change. What is the right way to write this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/1271/

Comment: Why include them in the markup to begin with?

Comment: `.slice(-5).remove()` works. What is the problem. `$('h3 .ui-accordion-header-icon.ui-icon.ui-icon-plus').slice(-5).remove()` would work.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Thank you this works.

Comment: @RickSanchez..Happy to help you..;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header-icon.ui-icon.ui-icon-plus:not(:last-child)').remove();
```

```js
$('.ui-accordion-header-icon.ui-icon.ui-icon-plus:not(:last-child)').remove();
```

```css
body * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
body *::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-11" aria-controls="ui-id-12" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="job-title job-title2">title</span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
    <br>
    <span class="subtext">subtext</span>
    <br>
</h3>
<div>
  Content
</div>
```

It's worth noting though that if you're consistently and unconditionally removing elements rendered to the browser those elements should not be in the HTML to begin with, and a server-side solution should be pursued instead, otherwise you're needlessly wasting bandwidth sending redundant/unnecessary HTML and user-resources running JavaScript to remove those elements.

Answer (score 0):

All spans with class name ".ui-accordion-header-icon" will be removed **except** first one

```
$('.ui-accordion-header span.ui-accordion-header-icon:not(:first)').remove()
```